# Audio cutting out at certain points

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I'm trying to listen to a podcast through Apple's headphones on my Macbook Pro (Retina, 13 Inch, mid 2014), running OS X 10.10.1, but the audio keeps cutting out.

When the audio cuts out, the following log messages appear in the Console app:

```
26/11/14 18:27:51,370 AirPlayUIAgent[348]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.369515 PM [AirPlayAVSys] AirPlay became the default audio device
26/11/14 18:27:51,378 discoveryd[51]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartBrowsingForKey: '_raop' Browsing service started
26/11/14 18:27:51,379 discoveryd[51]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartBrowsingForKey: '_airplay' Browsing service started
26/11/14 18:27:51,407 SystemUIServer[198]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.407192 PM [AirPlayAVSys] AirPlay became the default audio device
26/11/14 18:27:51,437 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.436712 PM [AirPlay] Set up for stream GeneralAudio, PCM/44100/16/2 -> ALAC/44100/16/2
26/11/14 18:27:51,437 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.436854 PM [AirPlay] Available DNS names: Infra [84383554262E@Julia\032-\032MacBook\032Air._raop._tcp.local.%4], P2P [intentionally disabled]
26/11/14 18:27:51,437 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.436997 PM [AirPlay] Pairing not required. Connect over Infra with "Julia - MacBook Air" via 84383554262E@Julia\032-\032MacBook\032Air._raop._tcp.local.%4
26/11/14 18:27:51,438 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.437740 PM [AirPlay] Add Peer without AWDL at MAC <<NULL>> with infra critical
26/11/14 18:27:51,438 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.437835 PM [AirPlay] MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 has 0 connections, 1 require infrastructure
26/11/14 18:27:51,000 kernel[0]: IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlPeerTrafficRegistration Clearing AirPlay peer 00:00:00:00:00:00
26/11/14 18:27:51,438 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:51.438200 PM [AirPlay] Register AirPlay traffic for AWDL at MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 with target infra critical PeerIndication=2 err=0
26/11/14 18:27:51,000 kernel[0]: IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlPeerTrafficRegistration Clearing AirPlay peer 00:00:00:00:00:00
26/11/14 18:27:51,000 kernel[0]: IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlPeerTrafficRegistration Clearing AirPlay peer 00:00:00:00:00:00
26/11/14 18:27:55,436 coreaudiod[597]: 2014-11-26 06:27:55.436424 PM [AirPlay] ### Start taking too long...continuing asynchronously
```

Every time it happens, the first message seems to be `AirPlay became the default audio device`, but I'm not currently using any airplay devices as far as I'm aware. How do I stop this from happening?

Rebooting doesn't help. Also, I'm in a library, so I currently can't test playing audio without headphones.

Comment: Which Apple Headphones?

Comment: The standard earbuds that come with an iPhone. I bought a new pair yesterday. They're from apple, not some other vendor.

Answer (score 1):

When I asked this question, I only had one option in the audio output devices list in my audio preferences. When I went back some time later, I noticed an option called `[someone's name] - Macbook Air`. I accidentally clicked it, and quickly set the setting back to my headphones. This seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: that "someone" wont be happy not getting your music to play any more :)